# Cassandra sstable2json doesn't works

Tags: debugging, nosql, cassandra, data-export

I'm try to export data from cassandra using sstable2json but when i try to run the command

`sstable2json /var/lib/cassandra/data/S2B_development/users-g-110-Data.db`

an error occurs

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
no non-system tables are defined
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: no non-system tables are defined
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.SSTableExport.main(SSTableExport.java:414)`

cassandra version: 0.8

Comment: Does the table exist in Cassandra that you are trying to export? The error is saying Cassandra can't find any table definitions. It needs these to know the validators and comparators for your table.

Comment: I have a user column family in my db

Comment: I suggest upgrading to a version of Cassandra that's not 2+ years old.  Nobody remembers the quirks of 0.8 anymore.

Comment: Also: sstable2json is a developers debugging tool, not an export tool for users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Example of how to get output from sstable2json

For the benefit of other developers:

**1.** Start Cassandra
 **2.** Fire up cqlsh
 **3.** Create a keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test WITH replication = 
    {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1};
```

**4.** Create a CF

```
CREATE TABLE test.test2
(
  key varchar PRIMARY KEY, 
  string varchar, 
  number int, 
  flag boolean
);
```

**5.** Populate the CF with a key (or lots of keys...)

```
INSERT INTO test.test2 (key, string, number, flag)
VALUES ('first_key', 'varchuuur', 312, false);
```

**6.** Flush the data (so it gets saved from the memtable into an sstable)
 **7.** Stop Cassandra
 **8.** run sstable2json

```
./bin/sstable2json /var/lib/cassandra/data/test/test2/test-test2-jb-1-Data.db;
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "66697273745f6b6579","columns": 
    [
      ["","",1378042590383000], 
      ["flag","true",1378042590383000], ["number","312",1378042590383000], 
      ["string","varchuuur",1378042590383000]
    ]
  }
]
```